# Identify minimum unique element of array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, unique, minimum

Allow me to emphasise the fact that I am very much a beginner, a fact that I am sure is evident in my code.

I need to define a function that identifies the LOWEST UNIQUE (only occurs once) value of an input array, however my current approach is flawed.

I think I am struggling to integrate each aspect of the problem.

I begin by sorting the values of the input array from highest to lowest through the implementation of a nested loop . I then proceed to set all of the values that appear more than once to zero. Finally, I identify the minimum unique value of the altered array and return it. If no unique value exists in the array, I return -1.

I've been permitted to assume that each element of the input array will be both positive and greater than zero and its length will be at least 1.

```
int minUnique(int *values, int length)

{

int i, j, temp, min = values[0];

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {           /* sorting */
            for (j = 0; j < length - 1; j++) {
                if (values[j] < values[j +1]) {
                    temp = values[j + 1];
                    values[j + 1] = values[j];
                    values[j] = temp;               
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
            printf(" %d", values[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {          /* setting 0 */
            if (values[i] == values[i + 1]) {
                values[i] = 0;
                values[i + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
       for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
            printf("  %d", values[i]); 
    }
    for (i = 1; i < length - 1; i++) {          /* identifying min */
        if ((values[i] < min) && (values[i] != 0)) {
            min = values[i];
        } else {
            count++;
            } 
        } if (count == length) {
            return -1; 
    } else {
        return min;
    }
}
```

Were I to enter an array such as values[12] = {3, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 8, 4, 5, 8, 12, 11}, I would expect it to be reorganised as values[12] = {12, 11, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3} and 6 to be returned.

My code is currently returning 3.

The code is not generating any error messages.

note: you can disregard the printf lines - they are simply there to help me understand what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pseudocode:

```
1. Sort from lowest to highest.
2. Iterate over the sorted array and return the first element whose neighbors are different.
```

The first step can be accomplished using the `qsort()` standard library function.

Comment: @Hsch2606: If you sort an array from lowest to highest, the first element is the minimum element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for setting the duplicate elements to zero does not work in case an element is duplicated 3 times (or any odd number of times)

Also, you can sort the array as from lowest to highest. The first non zero element after removing any duplicates will be your answer.

The full code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int minUnique(int *values, int length)
{
  int i, j, temp;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {           
    /* sorting */
    for (j = 0; j < length - 1; j++) {
      if (values[j] > values[j +1]) {
        temp = values[j + 1];
        values[j + 1] = values[j];
        values[j] = temp;               
      }
    }          
  }  
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
    printf(" %d", values[i]);
  }

  i=0;                              // Remove Duplicates
  while (i < length)
  {
    j=1;
    int dup = 0;
    while (values[i] == values[i+j])
    {
      values[i+j] = 0;
      dup = 1;
      j++;
    }
    if (dup == 1)
      values[i] = 0;
    i = i+j;  
  }
  printf ("\n"); 
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
    printf("  %d", values[i]); 
  }

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {          /* identifying min */
    if (values[i] != 0)
    {
      return (values[i]);
    }
  }
  return (-1); // no duplicates
}  

int main(void)
{
  int arr[] = {3, 7, 5, 6, 3, 3, 8, 4, 5, 8, 12, 11};
  int min = minUnique(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
  printf ("\nMinimum is %d\n",min);
  return 0;
}
```